# Solving a second order differential equation - Force depending on displacement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I know that an object starts moving along the $y$ axis with initial speed $v_o$ and that the force acting on this object is 
$$F(t) = -c\cdot y(t)$$
I need to find the expression for $y$ in terms of time. 
Therefore, 
$$F(t) = m \frac{dv}{dt} = m \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}$$
$$m \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = c \cdot y(t)$$
$$\frac{1}{y(t)} d^2y = \frac{c}{m} dt^2 $$ 
I have never studied differential equations before, I came across this problem when I during leisurely-reading of a Physics book. Can this equation be solved in an easy, quite intuitive way?

Comment: You have to choose: either "easy", or "intuitive" way. The way proposed by Galc127 is easy, but I would say that the physical intuition is lost. To save some of it, multiply both sides of $y'' + \frac{c}{m} y = 0$ by $2y'$ and observe that $2 y' y'' + 2 \frac{c}{m} y y' = ((y')^2 + \frac{c}{m} y^2)'$, so $(y')^2 + \frac{c}{m} y^2$ is constant along a solution (this is just conservation of energy). If you fix the total energy, you can express $y'$ as a function of $y$, and solve the resulting separable equation. In your case, calculations are terrible, but in nonlinear case that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes - should be $F(t)=ma=m\dfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}$ and $m\dfrac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}t^2}=-cy(t)$. The equation is $$my''+cy=0$$ We guess a solution of the form $y=e^{\lambda t}$ and the equation becomes $$m\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+ce^{\lambda t}=0\implies \lambda^2+\frac{c}{m}=0$$ Solving the quadratic equation you will have two solutions. Each linear combination of them is a solution to the equation.